# Using Jest with Vue, Jest appears to choke on an HTML comment in a .vue file

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Below is the output I'm seeing when I run Jest:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /home/ubuntu/chat-app/frontend/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import _Promise from "../../core-js/promise";
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      11 |                     {{ current_nickname }}
      12 |
    > 13 |                     <!-- https://linearicons.com/free#cdn -->
         |                                                 ^
      14 |                     <span class="lnr-button">
      15 |                         <svg class="lnr lnr-pencil" @click="prompt_nickname()"><use xlink:href="#lnr-pencil" /></svg>
      16 |                     </span>

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
      at src/components/ChatApp.vue:13:49
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/ChatApp.vue:219:3)
```

It seems to be choking on HTML comments.

What might the issue be?

Here are the other relevant config files:

`babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

`jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
        moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'vue'],
        transform: {
                '^.+\\.vue$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest',
                '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$':
                'jest-transform-stub',
                '^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest'
        },
        moduleNameMapper: {
                '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
        },
        snapshotSerializers: ['jest-serializer-vue'],
        transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/']
};
```

Not sure what the issue is, help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I am getting the same error, the only difference in my case are 1. I am using `transformIgnorePatterns` and 2. I am using bable preset as `"@babel/preset-env",`

Comment: Even I have the same error for using child component within the component to be tested. Has anyone got any clue to resolve this? If yes, please share the steps to get rid of this error.